# How do I test Facebook share on Android Virtual Device

Tags: android, facebook

I created a facebook share button in my app.  I would like to test it on my virtual device.  But it does not have the Facebook App on it.  How do I test sharing on my virtual device?

Comment: Try dragging Facebook apk to your virtual device, it should install the app. Login with the id you registered your app on.

Answer (score 0):

Sir you have to use your mobile phone for that . copy apk file from ur project. install and check it .

Answer (score 0):

Go to the downloads page for the Android SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads

From there, you can download the latest Facebook apk at the time of the SDK releases.

Do 'adb install' for the apk that you download.

Comment: where do I do the "ADB Install" in Android Studio?